# WPF TextBox with IsReadOnly property set to true can still be edited

Tags: wpf, .net-3.5

I'm using a TextBox and for some reasons it needs to be Read Only.
I won't argue the reasons here. I know I can use TextBlock or Label to display non-editable content, but in that case, unfortunately, there are TextBox.

```
<TextBox IsReadOnly="True" Text="{Binding totalAmount, Mode=OneWay, StringFormat={}{0:C2}}" TextAlignment="Right" />
```

Is anybody know if there is a known issue with it? 
I'm using WPF 3.5

Comment: I set TextBox IsReadOnly = true and it is readonly. Exact same with yours. You might have something code behind that changes it.

Comment: I thought about it, but what's strange is that there is no name and no style changing anything... But you're right, there is probably something because if I create a sample project with only a textbox on the MainWindow, it is actually read only.

Comment: Can you share some more XAML code?

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't use a Textblock?

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding totalAmount, Mode=OneWay, StringFormat={}{0:C2}}" TextAlignment="Right"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a TextBlock is not the answer because it is a completely different control. IsReadOnly is a very useful state for a TextBox and it can be toggled true/false via data binding. As per MSDN, if the text box is read-only, no user input or edits are allowed, but programmatic changes can be made. The user can still select text, and the cursor still appears. It is also not grayed out as it would be when disabled.

To answer the question, the most probable reason why your TextBox is not displaying as ReadOnly is because there is a style overriding the behavior. Please search your code for any style which might be implicitly applied to all TextBox types:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    ...
</Style>
```

You could also try specifying your own explicit blank style and see if it helps

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox" />
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```